# How to add up four digit numbers in one Excel cell?

Tags: excel

How can I add up 4 digit numbers separately that are in one cell?

For example, I want to have as output the sum of the first two digits + the other two like 12+12, then another output to calculate separately 1+2+1+2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `1212 = 24`, write `1212` in cell `A1` and try like this:

`=LEFT(A1,2)+RIGHT(A1,2)`

To make `1212 = 6`, you have to introduce `MID()` to the solution:

`=MID(A1,1,1)+MID(A1,2,1)+MID(A1,3,1)+MID(A1,4,1)`

Answer (score 2):

To get the sum of all digits in **A1** use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MID($A$1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1))
```

To get the sum of the pairs of digits, use:

```
=RIGHT(A1,2)+LEFT(A1,2)
```

Please be aware that the first equation uses the *INDIRECT()* function which is volatile.  It will be a little slower that a non-volatile solution

**EDIT#1:**

Several good alternatives are discussed in [Daily Dose Article](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/10/03/summing-the-digits-of-a-number/)

Comment: @Bathsheba  I will change my answer.  I have been looking for an alternative using the *INDEX()* function, but no luck so far.

Comment: @Bathsheba  Update done...........I also found a good article..............